# MockInterceptor returning content in wrong format

Tags: kotlin, encoding, character-encoding, fileinputstream

I created a mock-interceptor for my tests, that, after hours of debugging, turned out to be the source of a hundred crashes.
The exception, that´s being thrown is from Retrofit with the OkHttpClient:

```
java.io.IOException: canceled due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: message == null
```

Can´t give you the full stack trace, since the run log notorically denies returning it. However, somehow I still managed to get the line, that causes it (since one single time it got displayed), and found out it is in my MockInterceptor, which looks the following:

```
package package.app

import okhttp3.*
import okio.Buffer
import okio.BufferedSource
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream

class MockInterceptor(private val stream: InputStream) : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val body = MockUpBody(stream)
        val content = body.bytes().toString()
        return Response.Builder()
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
            // This is essential as it makes response.isSuccessful() returning true.
            .code(200)
            .request(chain.request())
            .body(body)
            .build() -> last mentioned line in stack trace
    }
}
class MockUpBody(private val stream: InputStream) : ResponseBody() {
    override fun contentType(): MediaType? {
        return null
    }

    override fun contentLength(): Long {
        //Means length is unknown beforehand
        return -1
    }

    override fun source(): BufferedSource? {
        return try {
            Buffer().readFrom(stream)
        } catch (exception : IOException) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
}
```

The stream I am reading in comes from a file having the following content:

```
{
  "message" : "Vous ajoutez ces offre avec succes",
  "backend-id": "1234567abc2346789def"
}
```

Further debugging showed me, that this is read correctly, since the body.byteStream().toString function returns

```
[size=97 text={\r\n  "message" : "Vous ajoutez ces offre avec succes",\r\n  "backe…].inputStream()
```

which is still pretty human readable,
but for some reason, when I ask for the bytes().toString() (which I guess the HttpClient also does), it gets messed up, returning the following:

```
[B@2e30b66
```

The bytes are being produced by responseBodys internal function call:

```
source.readByteArray();
```

So now, that we know, there´s a conversion error, my big question is: Where do I grab the problem to solve it? Do I need to convert my JSON file into a mess of bytes and paste that into the file? Or can I somehow change the style the stream is read, so it gets correctly converted in the code?

For further interest, the stream is got like this:

```
val stream : InputStream = InstrumentationRegistry
            .getInstrumentation()
            .context.assets.open("new_message.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.bytes()` function is probably returning a byte-array (`byte[]`), correct? The `.toString()` method of arrays (as of objects on default) returns their type and hash (which looks like the output you received). To actually convert a byte-array to a `String`, you need to explicitly convert it:

```java
var string = new String(bytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```